# Pytest: unable to specify parameter and count simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm trying to run a test with a parameter multiple times using the --count option.
This doesn't work since the --count option changes the collected test names with the numbers.
Simple code with parameterized test:

```py
import pytest
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
pytestmark = pytest.mark.register()


@pytest.mark.parametrize("param_a", [("val1"), ("val2"), ("val3")])
def test_func(submgt_controller, param_a):
    pass
```

Running the tests:

```
(venv) [bob@bob tests]$ pytest test_demo.py --collect-only

collected 3 items
<Package /bob/tests>
  Folder containing all testcases.
  <Module test_demo.py>
    <Function test_func[val1]>
    <Function test_func[val2]>
    <Function test_func[val3]>

========================================================================================================= no tests ran in 0.04s ==========================================================================================================
(venv) [bob@bob tests]$ pytest test_demo.py --collect-only --count=2

collected 6 items
<Package /bob/tests>
  Folder containing all testcases.
  <Module test_demo.py>
    <Function test_func[val1-1-2]>
    <Function test_func[val1-2-2]>
    <Function test_func[val2-1-2]>
    <Function test_func[val2-2-2]>
    <Function test_func[val3-1-2]>
    <Function test_func[val3-2-2]>

========================================================================================================= no tests ran in 0.04s ==========================================================================================================
(venv) [bob@bob tests]$ pytest test_demo.py::test_func[val1] --collect-only --count=2

collected 0 items

========================================================================================================= no tests ran in 0.05s ==========================================================================================================
ERROR: not found: /bob/tests/test_demo.py::test_func[val1]
(no name '/bob/tests/test_demo.py::test_func[val1]' in any of [<Module test_demo.py>])

(venv) [bob@bob tests]$ pytest test_demo.py::test_func[val1-1-2] --collect-only --count=2

collected 1 item
<Package /bob/tests>
  Folder containing all testcases.
  <Module test_demo.py>
    <Function test_func[val1-1-2]>

========================================================================================================= no tests ran in 0.04s ==========================================================================================================
```

How can I run a specific subtest multiple times?

Comment: You might better ask this in the [pytest-repeat](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-repeat) project - my guess is that this is not supported.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to be supported. Being able to have a wildcard in the parameter selection part of calling a test would also be helpful here.

Comment: You may create a feature request with this proposal (or even better a PR that does this).